# How to save bucketed DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save a dataFrame using bucketBy

```
df.write.bucketBy("column").format("parquet").save()
```

But this producing the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'save' does not support bucketing right now;
```

Is there any other way to save the result of bucketBy?

Comment: DataFrameWriter.bucketBy is available to bucket the output like Hive does. Please refer the API doc at https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#bucketBy(int,%20java.lang.String,%20scala.collection.Seq)

Answer (score 6):

Till now, **spark 2.1**, `save` doesn't support bucketing as noted in the error message.

The method `bucketBy` buckets the output by the given columns and when/if it's specified, the output is laid out on the file system similar to Hive's bucketing scheme.

There is a JIRA in progress working on [Hive bucketing support
[SPARK-19256]](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19256).

So the only available operation after bucketing would be `saveAsTable` which saves the content of the `DataFrame`/`Dataset` as the specified table.

And since mainly spark connects with hive so actually you are saving it to `hive`.

So what you are actually isn't possible for the time being with spark.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when loading a dataframe, partitioning it by a column, sorting it and then performing save(). Does that imply, unless the data is saved in hive, we cannot use this feature? Thanks.                                                                  
  
  write().format("com.databricks.spark.avro").partitionBy("dynamic_col").sortBy("dynamic_col").save();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575541/reading-bucketed-directory-with-mani-manifest-files
Any thoughts on this q would be greatly appreciated 