# reading bucketed directory with .mani/ manifest files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a directory as below and need to read `spark.read.parquet('car_data')` keeping year as a column without reading the .mani (manifest files). I can read the data using wildcard `'car_data/year=*/*.parquet'` but this doesn't add keep year as a column.

The problem I'm having is if I load the directory, as you would with bucketed data I get an error as Spark tries to read the mani files as parquet but then I can't use the wildcards to skip them! Is there another way of doing this?

Edit: I've now also tried `spark.read.load('/car_data/', format='parquet', pathGlobFilter='*.parquet')` and I still get the same error, having a look around it looks like this is only available in spark 3.0 and I'm on 2.4, but there must be another way

Thanks in advance peeps!

```
car_data
 |---year=2018
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet.mani
 |---year=2019
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet.mani
 |---year=2020
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet.mani
```

Comment: I added a solution in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332006/reading-partitioned-parquet-in-spark/67577708#67577708

Answer (score 1):

You can create the list of files and pass only the list of files you need to read to spark.read.parquet()

```
spark.read.parquet("/path/to/dir/part_1.gz", "/path/to/dir/part_2.gz")
```

Starting from Spark 1.6.0, partition discovery only finds partitions under the given paths by default. For the below example directory structure, if users pass path/to/table/gender=male to either SparkSession.read.parquet or SparkSession.read.load, gender will not be considered as a partitioning column.

If users need to specify the base path that partition discovery should start with, they can set basePath in the data source options. For example, when path/to/table/gender=male is the path of the data and users set basePath to path/to/table/, gender will be a partitioning column.

```
path
└── to
    └── table
        ├── gender=male
        │   ├── ...
        │   │
        │   ├── country=US
        │   │   └── data.parquet
        │   ├── country=CN
        │   │   └── data.parquet
        │   └── ...
        └── gender=female
            ├── ...
            │
            ├── country=US
            │   └── data.parquet
            ├── country=CN
            │   └── data.parquet
            └── ...
```

Please refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery for more information. Taken the above directory structure from there.